# MAMP 5 (Nginx) - How can I extend timeout in my MAMP setup?

Tags: nginx, mamp, php.ini

I have a PHP script that runs for over the default 60 seconds, however the page returns a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

How can i extend the timeout so the page returns a result at the end of the PHP script.

I am running:

- MAMP 5
- Nginx
- PHP 7.1.3 (loaded)

I have looked at other sites and answers, but because I'm running MAMP, the locations I need to add these changes aren't necessarily the same.

Some places I've found similar but not exact answers to my issue.

[https://mamchenkov.net](https://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2016/08/04/504-gateway-timeout-error-on-nginx-fastcgi-php-fpm/)

[https://www.scalescale.com](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/#)

[https://asdqwe.net](https://asdqwe.net/blog/solutions-504-gateway-timeout-nginx/)

[https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002268/prevent-nginx-504-gateway-timeout-using-php-set-time-limit)

Changes I have made at the moment:

in MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf added fastcgi_read_timeout 300 in

```
location ~* /MAMP[^-]*(.*)$ {
        root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
        index            index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            include          fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

in MAMP/conf/php7.1.3/php.ini updated max_execution_time = 300

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 300     ; Maximum execution time of each 
script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

I'm just a little confused if these are the places I should be entering these parameters or elsewhere for the MAMP implementation i'm using. Please note the changes allows the PHP script to continue running after the 504 response is returned, but i want to eliminate the 504 response altogether.